# Android- How to check the type of Intent Filters Programmatically?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent, nfc

I'm Creating an android application with two Activities(Activity1 and Activity2) where I need to open the app in two ways .

**Way 1 :   By NFC Card**

In this way ,I need to open the Activity1. ie., If I swipe the Card I need to open Activity1.

**Way 2 : By Icon**

In this way,I need to open the Activity 2 .ie., If the user click the icon the Activity2 must be opened .

My AndroidManifest.xml is shown below ,

```
   ...............
   ...............
   ...............
   <activity 
        android:name=".Activity1"
       android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
          >
   <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>



            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>





    </activity>
   .......................
   .......................
   .......................
```

In Activity1 I just tried to get the type by

```
  if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) 


 {
 // Here I'm dealing with Activity1.
 }



 else
 {
 // Here I've set an Intent to go to Activity2.
 }
```

You can look at else block where I've set an Intent to go to Activity2.But I need to go directly to Activity2 without getting into Activity1.

How to achieve that ? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The activity chosen to be opened if the user clicks the icon in the launcher is determined by the `LAUNCHER` category. So it should work if you define the second activity in the Manifest and move these lines to it, i.e. remove it from `Activity1` and add it to `Activity2`:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

Then whenever the user invokes your application, `Activity2` is triggered but `Activity1` will still be triggered by the other intents.

**References:**

- [Intents and Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)