# Retrieving triggering Intent from Application object

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a heavy-duty init process that I would like to run in 2 different places, depending on how the application started.
The heavy-init runs in background with an AsyncTask.

The cases are:

- if the application was started from a Widget (via Intent), I need to make the heavy init inside the Application.onCreate
- in any other cases, I need to make the heavy init inside the Activity.onStart

In other words, I'd like to know if inside the Application.onCreate there's a way to retrieve the triggering Intent.

thanks
Fabio

Answer (score 0):

As it is reffeered in this link : [Android- How to check the type of Intent Filters Programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469815/android-how-to-check-the-type-of-intent-filters-programmatically)
You can use the `getAction()` of your intent to know what type of intent launched the activity.

Comment: An application doesn't receive any intent only activities do. If you want to know which intent was send it has to be done in an activity